# How to rename the wp-config.php file once under version control?

Tags: wp-config, git, version-control

```
git clone git://develop.git.wordpress.org/ develop
```

After cloning the core development repository with Git, considering the files and folders are under version control, how can the config files be renamed to `wp-config.php` and `wp-tests-config.php`?

```
.git
src/
tests/
tools/
...
wp-config-sample.php
wp-tests-config-sample.php
```

I'm aware I can do `git mv wp-config-sample.php wp-config.php` but now my working copy is different from the upstream repository.

Ref: https://make.wordpress.org/core/2014/01/15/git-mirrors-for-wordpress/

Comment: You can make another file 'local-wp-config.php' that is conditionally loaded from 'wp-config.php' if exists. You can then add that file to .gitignore. Your local config will be localized to your setup and never uploaded and the process can work w/all team members. You'll have to change 'wp-config.php' to support that type of setup but it works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not rename or modify the sample files unless such modifications are intended for contribution - they are there for reference. The files `wp-config.php` and `wp-tests-config.php` are explicitly ignored by `.gitignore`. Simply create them as new files yourself (or, if you'd like to use the sample files verbatim create symlinks to the sample files) to avoid unnecessary disparity with upstream.

Comment: Thanks @bosco, that's nicely clarified what should be done.